# How to get url and add as an input value

Tags: jquery, url

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the current url and add it to an input field.

I'm using this currently and it doesn't work for me:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').val(window.location.hash);
   });
</script>
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.8

I'm actually just trying to get the root domain and the first sub directory only. So for instance if the domain that this function was on is domain.com/sub/sub/sub I would want it to only get domain.com/sub

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/39Sha/ location.hash grabs the hash component of your URL. It doesn't sound like that's what you want. Search splitting strings at slashes on SO for how to grab just the part you want.

Answer (score 0):

by that you access the hash value of an url like domain.com/something/index.html#hash

window.location is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/39Sha/1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').val(window.location);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.href` for the URL and capture the needed part with a [`regular expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
var re = /:\/\/(.+?\/.+?)\//;
var parts = location.href.match(re);
$('input').val(parts[1]);
```

Comment: This gave me the full URL I just need the domain and first sub. Thanks tough!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `window.location` is: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456616/how-to-get-url-and-add-as-an-input-value` (this page, in fact), and you want the first sub-directory (in this case `questions`):

```
    // on this page: 'http://'
var protocol = window.location.protocol + '//',
    // on this page: 'stackoverflow.com'
    domain = window.location.hostname,
    // on this page: 'questions'
    directory = window.location.pathname.substring(1).split('/').shift(),
    // 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions'
    url = protocol + domain + '/' + directory;
$('input').val(url);
```

References:

- [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Comment: This is giving me only the first sub and not including the domain.com. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This still didn't seem to work. The above answer did work for me though. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `window.location.href` or `window.location`:

You can see it working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/hJKkY/1/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').val(window.location.href);
   });
```

Comment: This gave me the full URL I just need the domain and first sub. Thanks tough!